# How to solve onbackpressed deprecated in java on android studio project API level 34

Tags: java, android, android-studio, deprecated

I created a Java project on Android Studio. Android target API level 34 but the problem is onbackpressed deprecated. you can see this problem

```
   @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Your `onBackPressed` isn't actually doing anything, so just...delete your override of the method? You'll need to show what you are actually trying to do if you want help [intercepting the back button](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/custom-back) in a way that supports the [Predictive Back Gesture](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/custom-back/predictive-back-gesture).

Answer (score 6):

Use this in your `onCreate()`

```
OnBackPressedCallback onBackPressedCallback = new OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
        @Override
        public void handleOnBackPressed() {
            // handle backpressed here
        }
    };
    getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(this,onBackPressedCallback);
```

Comment: this works but then normal back actions stop working so you have to tell android where to go.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(new ...)` in your `onCreate()`.

You can test its execution by displaying a toast in the callback for example.